# Prove that : every continuous map $f : A \to S^n$ can be extended over some neighborhood of A

Tags: general-topology

That is one of my topology exercises.

I want to prove that if A is a close subset of metric space, then the continuous map can be extended over the whole space.

Maybe i can extend it over $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ first, then use the Homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ and $S^n$ to complete it?

Any hint would be helpful to me!

---

Edit

> I want to prove that if A is a close subset of metric space, then the continuous map can be extended over the whole space.

That should be

> I want to prove that if A is a close subset of metric space, then the continuous map can be extended over the neighborhood of $A$.

Sorry to make you confused.

Comment: There is no homeomorphism between $\mathbb R^{n-1}$ and $S^n$. There is a homeomorphism between $S^n - \{p\}$ and $\mathbb R^n$ however. Also it is not clear what metric space $A$ is a closed subset of. It is not true in general that if $A$ is a closed subset of a metric space $X$ then $f$ extends to a map $X \rightarrow S^n$

Comment: @Noel Lundström I'm sorry that i made a mistake on the detail part : ' the whole space ' should be ' neighborhood of A '. I will correct it. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to prove that if A is a close subset of metric space, then the continuous map can be extended over the whole space.

This is not true. Consider $X=\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, $A=S^n$ and $f:A\to S^n$ the identity and note that $f$ cannot be extended to whole $X$ because that would mean that $S^n$ is a retract of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. And this cannot happen (by comparing $n$-th homology groups for example).

> Maybe i can extend it over $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ first, then use the Homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ and $S^n$ to complete it?

There is no such homeomorphism. Obviously dimensions don't agree. But it doesn't matter, there is no homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $S^m$ regardless of $n,m$. You seem to think about homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $S^n\backslash\{p\}$ ([the stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection)). But I don't see how we can utilize it here.

---

Anyway indeed, every $f:A\to S^n$ can be extended to some open neighbourhood $U$ of $A$ in $X$ if $X$ is metrizable (or more generally normal). You do it as follows: first define

$$g:A\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$$
$$g(x)=f(x)$$

i.e. $g$ is the composition of $f$ and the inclusion $i:S^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Then we apply [Tietze extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem) (here the assumption about $X$ being normal is important) and obtain the extension

$$G:X\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$$
$$G(x)=g(x)\text{ if }x\in A$$

So how to pass from $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ back to $S^n$? Well, we consider $U=G^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\backslash\{0\})$, which is open in $X$, and the restriction

$$G':U\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\backslash\{0\}$$
$$G'=G_{|U}$$

The crucial observation is that $A\subseteq U$. We are very close now. The final step is to take the retraction

$$r:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\backslash\{0\}\to S^n$$
$$r(v)=\frac{v}{\lVert v\rVert}$$

and define $F:U\to S^n$ by $F=r\circ G'$. Note that $F$ extends our initial $f$.

Comment: That is very helpful! I think i made a mistake on the detail part, i will correct it.